# UDP packets are not sent on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets, udp, asyncsocket

I use this library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

My test code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class GCDAsyncUdpSocket;

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController
{
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket;
}
```

.m:

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h"
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;

@implementation ThirdViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [udpSocket bindToPort:7744 error:nil];
    [udpSocket beginReceiving:nil];
    [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
    //[udpSocket connectToHost:@"127.0.0.1" onPort:55544 error:nil];

    NSData *data = [@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //[udpSocket sendData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"127.0.0.1" port:55544 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

But the package is not sent. I used this packet sniffer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetpeeper/

In the library there is an example of a client (for Mac), his packages I see. I tried to run the application on a real device, but nothing was sent, too (address, of course, was the other). What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening on port `7744` and you're transmitting to port `55544`. You should be transmitting to the same port as you're listening at. i.e. the send should be:

```
[udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"127.0.0.1" port:7744 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

An educated guess as to the reason packetkeeper isn't seeing the packets is because they are not going out any network interface - it's a general optimization that packets for the `lo` device (`127.0.0.1`) do not go out on the wire; they are just looped around locally. Most packet interception devices cannot detect packets of this type.

**Edit** You need at least two `GDCAsyncUdpSocket`s - one for the client, one for the server. The easiest way to accomplish this is to have two separate applications, one running as the server, the other running as the client.

This ThirdViewController is a UDP client of some form. When you issue the bindToPort, you need to use the port number `0`, this causes the OS to allocate a port for this system which is used for listening. This is needed if you ever want to receive a packet sent from the server.

```
[udpSocket bindToPort:0 error:nil];
```

as an aside, I would always check for an error on bindToPort.

On the server side, you need to bind to a known port:

```
[serverSocket bindToPort:55544 error:nil];
```

On the client side, when you send a message you need to do (for the simulator):

```
[udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"127.0.0.1" port:55544 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

On the server side, when you receive the message in the `didReceiveData` handler, you are passed a `fromAddress`. This address corresponds to the address and port from `udpSocket`, and if you want to transmit a message back to the client, you can use:

```
[serverSocket sendData:data toAddress:fromAddress withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

I have had no difficulties sending packets to the `serverSocket` from the `udpSocket` and processing responses when I followed this methodology. I use wireshark on the Mac side to see packets coming from the iDevice. When I used the simulator, I sent to 127.0.0.1 and saw the responses on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed the listening port on the same, on which transmitting. I have tried to send on eth1, and again I do not see the package. Packets sent from the mac application I see, even if the address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: How do you determine the `toHost` address to use? Do you have the IP address of the iDevice on screen that you enter, because that is the address you must use unless you are using the broadcast address - if your desktop is on `192.168.1.5`, then the broadcast address is `192.168.1.255`. You can determine the IP address of your desktop from the `Network Preferences Pane`.

Comment: My computer is connected to a router and has an address `192.168.10.101`. When I try to send a packet from the iDevice, I choose this address as `toHost`. IDevice has address `192.168.10.102`. When I try to send from the simulator, I choose the address `127.0.0.1`. I also tried to choose `192.168.10.101`. enableBroadcast I set is `NO`.

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer - you are running a server socket to see the messages from the client? The client should not be binding to a specific port - it should use 0 to pick a port at random. The sever socket should bind to a specific port, and the client should send to that specified port.

Comment: I all did so. My mistake was in the other, now I found it. Thank you very much for your attention to my question!